# How many Primary key constraints can be included in a table definition?

Tags: sql, sql-server

anyone know How many Primary key constraints can be included in a table definition?
help thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be only one primary key in a table and since constraint comes from primary key that would make one primary key constraint again.

Edit: Just to clarify primary key constraint can only be one which can have multiple columns though in case of composite primary key.

Answer (score 2):

Read this and you will find an answer:

[Primary Key constraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933112%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

There is one more clarification

[Primary key constraints SQL Server 2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179610.aspx)

Comment: Then I suggest that you might not be up to the task of whatever qualification you're being examined for. The MS documentation is actually pretty good, besides which this is a basic DB concept and therefore it is explained extremely well in many, many places on the interwebs. It would have taken no real effort to Google this and find the answer in mere seconds.